# Declarative Jenkins pipeline: is it possible to build Dockerfile with SSH credentials?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up the following Jenkins pipeline:

1. Pipeline checked out from SCM
2. Build runs inside a Docker container
3. Docker image is built from a Dockerfile
4. Docker image needs SSH access, therefore `--ssh` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) is used

There's the [ssh-agent](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) plugin, but it can only be used *after* the container is built, which means docker layer cache can't be used. I could also use a scripted pipeline, but then it forces my whole pipeline to be scripted.

I also tried to pass the credentials file using `--secret` flag in docker, but I couldn't find a way to use credentials in `additionalBuildArgs`: if I call `credentials()`, I just get a non-transformed pipeline object. If this worked, it could actually be a solution:

```
agent {
    dockerfile {
        additionalBuildArgs('--secret id=secret,src=' + credentials('credential'))
    }
}
```

I also thought of moving out the agent definition outside the declarative pipeline object but found no way of using the agent later in `pipeline`.

Is there a way to make this work with declarative pipelines, or at least to keep most of it declarative?

Comment: Jenkins presumably has ssh access as well (to be able to get the source repository); is it easier to check everything you need out at the Jenkins layer and `COPY` it in the Dockerfile, without trying to make ssh access available during the image build?

Comment: It does have SSH access but there's some time lost for clone step that will always execute, as well as for context build. This might not be a big problem but what's worse -- one needs to create special cases for e.g. `pip` to be able to resolve those pre-provided dependencies, etc. It gets messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of posting this answer, it is not possible to accomplish that with a declarative pipeline. Transformation and execution of declarative agent declaration is not flexible enough to allow this kind of thing to happen. What is, however, possible, is to create a pipeline library function to call `docker.build` within an `sshagent` block. This, of course, will not be as clean as using declarative agents.

One can view source code of Docker integration here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy